# I have a typo in the forest of my group policy management

Tags: windows

is there a simple way I could just update the forest/domain name in my Group Policy Management it's only a single letter i missed. I've tried using rendom but it always fails with an error. One server contacted one server returns an error.

Comment: A dearth of details. We can't help you with only the information you provided. How about giving us some details.

Comment: @joeqwerty the domain name is supposed to be cosgrove.com.ng with a letter 's' but I mistakenly typed congrove.com.ng, with the letter 'n'. As I started looking for solutions I came across the domain rename tool rendom on windows server 2012. Which as I understand is for administrators that want to change their domain name completely.  But I still went ahead and tried it. However, it still fails at the rendom /prepare stage with this error Fail to prepare CosgrovePMO.congrove.com.ng :8599 1 server contacted, 1 server returned Errors. I'll like to know if there's an easier way to do it. Thanks.

Comment: @joeqwerty I've already added users to the domain otherwise I'd just do it all over again. Thank you.